# C++: error: opencv_core: No such file or directory even if the needed .so file is in /usr/lib/

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, cmake, linker

I am trying to compile a project from github that relies on Opencv.

I know that the opencv_core file must be "known" by the compiler. In my case I installed opencv via apt-get and so the needed `.so` and `.a` files are all in

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

To check if the compiler really looked into it I checked the directory

```
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/
```

Where  is a `x86_64-linux-gnu.conf` file, having the correct path like mentioned above. Furthermore, I created a opencv.conf file where I wrote the exact same path to the `.so` files.

If I look at the CMakeFile, OpenCV is included like this:

```
find_package(OpenCV QUIET REQUIRED COMPONENTS core highgui)
if(OpenCV_FOUND)
  message("Found OpenCV")
  include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
endif(OpenCV_FOUND)



add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/Simulator.cpp src/noiseutils.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} assimp CGAL noise ${LIBS}) 

add_executable(object src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(object ${PROJECT_NAME})
```

When I message out the `${LIBS}` I get the following:

```
lboost_system opencv_coreopencv_highgui
```

Which seems correct to me.

However after running cmake, and executing make I get presented with the following error:

> Linking CXX executable ../bin/object
>
> c++: error: opencv_core: No such file or directroy

followed by the usuual make error output.

Which seems odd to me, since the linker should know where the file is, due to the `.conf` files.

I also tried to update the `LD_LIBRRAY_PATH` so it now includes the path the `.so` files and executed the `sudo ldconfig` command, but this did not help.

After seeing, that error was caused from "`object`" - executable I changed the last line to:

```
target_link_libraries(object ${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBS})
```

Thinking it may need the flags from LIBS, too - however this did not solve the case.

I am out of ideas of what to do, thank you really much for any help.

I also tried to change the `find_package` command to the following line:

```
find_package(OpenCV QUIET REQUIRED COMPONENTS core highgui PATHS /usr/lib/x86_64-linux_gnu NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
```

I tried to intall a new version of cmake, which did not help.

I am in Docker-Image on a Server which runs Xubuntu.

But that did not help either.

Comment: You call `add_executable()` with "render_object", but  `target_link_libraries()` is called with "object". What is right? What is *PROJECT_NAME* in your case? For more information about the building, you may use `make V=1`, this shows **complete command lines** for building and linking.

Comment: sry was a typo from writing "object" is correct. PROJECT_NAME is just a variable for the projects name. I will use the v=1 and come back here soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This very well may not be your problem, but I suspect the formatting of the `${LIBS}` variable is the issue:

```
lboost_system opencv_coreopencv_highgui
             ^          XX
```

There is a space where `^` is, and no space between the opencv libs.  Minimal version on my system:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(hello)

find_package(OpenCV QUIET REQUIRED COMPONENTS core highgui)
if(OpenCV_FOUND)
  message("Found OpenCV")
  include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
endif(OpenCV_FOUND)

message(STATUS "The libraries: ${LIBS}") # important line
```

The important line of output for me:

```
-- The libraries: opencv_core;opencv_highgui
                             ^
```

Because for me `${LIBS}` had no value yet.  You might be mixing how you are representing things, lists or strings.  In my experience, prefer lists (relying on `;` as the delimiter).  So now (going in the reverse order and finding boost afterward), I can add beneath the above:

```
find_package(Boost QUIET REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)
if(Boost_FOUND)
    list(APPEND LIBS "${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
endif()

message(STATUS "With boost: ${LIBS}")
```

and I now have the following printed:

```
                          v              v
-- With boost: opencv_core;opencv_highgui;/long/path/to/my/lib/libboost_system-mt.so
```

Your `find_package(Boost ...)` may be giving something different, I have a custom boost compiled so I'm not sure.  But with the complete example I'd say

1. Make sure `boost` is being found correctly.
2. You should be worried if these variables already have the `l` in them (**`l`**`boost_system`).
3. `list(APPEND LIBS` is a safer alternative than `set`, it will work with `OpenCV_LIBS` as well!

Hopefully one of those gets you in the right direction!

Comment: This solved my issues, the path with the "append libs" did the trick. However, now I am at the old problem with opencv that it cannot find the LIBTIFF and so on, but this is for another question. So thank you really much

Comment: Nice!  Yeah as @Tsyvarev mentions, `make VERBOSE=1` can be very helpful in identifying what is wrong.  `cmake` only configures what you asked, you get the errors at build time.  As for LIBTIFF not being found, go find your `opencv_highgui` library (probably in `/usr/lib64` -- you can do `locate *libopencv*` assuming you have an up to date db [ `sudo updatedb` ]).  When I check `ldd /usr/lib64/libopencv_highgui.so` mine reveals where it thinks `libtiff` is -- verify yours is there!  If you moved it, create a symlink.  If it doesn't show up, `opencv` did not compile with `libtiff` x0

Comment: Actually it was a little bit strange, Anaconda provided an other version of libtiff so I had to do conda remove libtiff and then it worked, when I installed libtiff with sudp apt-get install libtiff4-dev

Comment: Ahh yeah so anaconda greedily puts itself in the _front_ of your path, it [looks like this](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install#removing-anaconda-path-from-bash-profile). But you can't really flip it to put `$PATH:/path/to/anaconda` because now system python will get found first.  Instead, if you really need the conda package, try forcing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to put the system libs (or specifically the imaging libs) first?  It'll be hard to get that configured correctly though...better to just leave the conda package out if you don't need it ;)